# Showing menu based on right click on point geometry in JavaScript

Tags: openlayers-2, events, vector

I have implemented a vector layer(using JavaScript) in OpenLayers which has a point geometry.

Now my requirement is to show menu just beside the point whenever we do right-click on the point.

Can we do this in OpenLayers?

Comment: It's doable, but not straight forward. Right clicks are not picked up by javascript by default (they are reserved for browser menus).

Comment: If you try OL 3 I wrote [an extension](https://github.com/jonataswalker/ol3-contextmenu) for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

there is an information [here](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/SelectFeature-js-right-click-td3890594.html) about right click select feature. i havent try it but it looks like it works.

> myMap is OpenLayers.Map object and myVectorLayer is...
>   OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.

```
myMap.div.oncontextmenu = function noContextMenu(e) {
    if(!e){ //dear IE...
        var e = window.event;
        e.returnValue = false;
    }

    var f = myVectorLayer.getFeatureFromEvent(e);
    alert(f);
    //f is the pointed vector.feature :)

    return false; //Prevent display of browser context menu
}
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: "getFeatureFromEvent(e)" was really a good pointer...I have used this to get point geometry(which is laid over vector feature) and further to show menu(for which I have used openlayer's popup)I have used (long,lat) of point. Following is the code which I have implmeneted to show menu besides with point geometry:

Comment: var f = vectorLayerForHoleMarkers.getFeatureFromEvent(e);                               popup = new OpenLayers.Popup("chicken",                            new OpenLayers.LonLat(f.geometry.x,f.geometry.y),
new OpenLayers.Size(200,200),true);
popup.closeOnMove = true;                                                myMap.addPopup(popup);

Comment: `myMap.div` ? `TypeError: map.div is undefined` ...